# What is the correct definition of pointer to a constant array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I want to implement a function who has to return a pointer to an array in C++, something like:

```
typedef double* ptr;
ptr func(size_t m) {
  return A[m];
}
```

where `A` is a 2-D array defined globally (or as a member of the implementing class).

Now, I want to ensure that the returned array cannot be modified by the caller. I was wondering how can I declare the return type of the function to guarantee this.

I have tried to define it as:

```
const ptr func(size_t m) {
  return A[m];
}
```

but I can write:

```
ptr x = func(5); 
x[10] = 20.4;
```

and the above compiles without any problems.

Comment: You should be returning `&A[m]` if you want a pointer to the array.

Comment: @chris `A` is already a 2-D array, i.e. something like `double** A` and the function returns the pointer to its m-th row.

Comment: That's not a 2D array, but a pointer to a pointer to a double. Returning `A[m]` returns a pointer to a double. There's no way to get a pointer to an array from a `double **`.

Answer (score 3):

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static double A[100][100];

const double* func(size_t m) {
      return A[m];
}

int main() {
    double * x = func(5);
    x[10] = 20.4;
}
```

GCC 4.8.1 reports:

```
foo.cc:10:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘const double*’ to ‘double*’ [-fpermissive]
  double * x = func(5);
                     ^
```

And Clang 3.3 reports:

```
foo.cc:10:11: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'double *' with an rvalue of type 'const double *'
        double * x = func(5);
                 ^   ~~~~~~~
```

---

And to flesh out ComicSansMS's comment, because the comment he is responding to was deleted:

```
typedef double* ptr;

const ptr func(size_t m) {
    return A[m];
}
```

This code is not the same as the code posted above. `const ptr` is a constant pointer to a double. The original code refers to a pointer to a constant double.

---

You could do something along these lines by doing:

```
typedef double* ptr;
typedef const double* cptr;

cptr func(size_t m) {
    return A[m];
}

int main() {
    ptr x = func(5);
    x[10] = 20.4;
}
```

Which would report an error:

```
so.cc:27:6: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'ptr' (aka 'double *') with an rvalue of type 'cptr' (aka 'const double *')
        ptr x = func(5);
            ^   ~~~~~~~
```

Comment: VC++ 2008 gives an error [C2440](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): `'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const double *' to 'double *'`

Comment: VC++ 2012: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const double *' to 'double *' Conversion loses qualifiers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried exactly the same code and I get an error. However, if I add a line `typedef double* ptr` and then replace all `double*` in the code with `ptr` the code would compile without any errors. What happens with `typedef`?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi That is because a `const ptr` in your code is a `double* const`, not a `double const*`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I see! is there a way to get it the correct way using the `typedef`?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi You'll need a second `typedef double const* const_ptr` and then return a `const_ptr` instead of a `const ptr` (i know, it's confusing).

Comment: And this is why `const` should always be written on the right.

Comment: @Simple: How would writing `const` on the right help in this situation? Given that the OP apparently did `typedef double *ptr; const ptr func(size_t m)…`, changing it to `ptr const func(size_t m)…` would have yielded the same behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If he wrote `ptr const` it would have instantly clicked that it meant `double* const`.

Comment: @Simple: I do not see that. Putting it on the right does not convey “this modifier applies to the whole type” any more than putting it on the left does. If a person does not see that the modifier applies to the whole type (rather than the pointed-to object) when the modifier is on the left, I see no reason they would see it when the modifier is on the right.

Answer (score 2):

`const double*` and `double const*` both indicate a pointer to a constant double. The user can modify where the pointer refers, but not the value pointed at.

`double * const` indicates a constant pointer to a double. The user can modify the value of the pointed to double, but not where the pointer refers.

`double const * const` indicates a constant pointer to a constant double. The user can not modify either the value of the double or where the pointer refers.